# Why can I not forward-declare a static function?

Tags: c++, static, forward-declaration

I need to forward-declare a class in my header file, like this:

```
class MyStaticClass;
```

I understand why one cannot forward-declare data members of this class. I used to think that you could however forward-declare functions. I would like to declare a static function of this class, like this:

```
class MyStaticClass;
static int MyStaticClass::AddTwoNumbers(const int a, const int b);
```

This gives me a compile error though:

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'MyStaticClass'
```

Why can this not be done? Or is there a secret way of doing this after all?

Comment: Why? You don't need to provide a forward declaration of a class member function. You just need to make sure the class definition is in scope before you use it.

Comment: In the project I'm working on, I cannot simply include the header of the file that I need, for reasons. Hence I'd like to just forward-declare it, and have it linked up by the linker.

Comment: In order to be able to say `SomeType::Anything` you need a full definition of `SomeType`.

Comment: This is not possible. If you need to call a member function without having the class definition in scope, use a regular (non-member) function to forward the call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not allowed because it would allow others to add member functions to a class without even editing the class itself.

Consider this,

```
struct X
{
    static void f(float a) { std::cout << a << std::endl; }
 private:
    static int _data; //inaccessible to non-member
};

X::f(0); //convert 0 (an int) to float, and call X::f().
```

Now imagine someone came and forward-declare the following function, just before including header which defines the above class:

```
static void X::f(int);
```

Now the previous call `X::f(0)` would give linker error (*unresolved name*) because now `0` wouldn't convert to `float`, because it does not need to as there is a *declared* function which accepts an `int`, though it is not defined — worse, if it is defined, then you wont even get the linker error and you would probably not easily know that a different function is being called.

Morever. `f(int)` can now access the `private` member `_data` as well — in this way, anyone can access any private/protected members just by adding functions at whim.